# Can a tenure decision be overturned a month before the decision letter is sent to faculty?

Tags: publications, phd, tenure-track

I am a grad student with an untenured faculty. Her tenure dossier was discussed last year and I have heard through the grapevine that she may be denied tenure the primary reasons being her lack of productivity (one article published, one in review at the time of ptc meeting in fall now accepted, 2 preprints both currently in review but not at the time of ptc meeting, all in 7 years) and not having graduated a student.

She threw me under the bus with a months notice that I absolutely had to defend by the year end, notwithstanding that my paper isn’t published and I can’t move on without it to any postdoctoral positions. She is now demanding that my paper ‘absolutely has to be accepted’ within 4 months (first round of reviews with major revision decision received in mid December) again for her tenure. This is nearly impossible given my experiments.

I am finding it very hard to find any sympathy for her because of her generally irresponsible behavior toward me since it is extremely unlikely she wasn’t aware of these tenure expectations before, and because she got a year of tenure extension because of the pandemic while I slaved in lab through it regardless.

My questions are:

1. if she is going to be denied tenure is even a last minute paper acceptance going to change the decision? I am concerned if we send out a less than thorough revised paper we will be rejected which will also have very negative consequences for me.
2. is it not considered her responsibility to see her student’s papers through to publication since I have killed myself for it over six and a half years? Does student outcome ever factor in making tenure decisions?

Comment: I will point out that you certainly want to graduate as soon as possible if your professor does not get tenure. You have more than a little interest in getting that paper published and your PhD in hand.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of side-information and it makes your question seem more like a rant than an actual question. I had trouble finding anything representing your title question in the body of your question. Can you take a step back and try to clarify what it is you are actually asking? It seems like you're asking if a paper published late in the tenure process can influence tenure; that does not sound like "overturning" anything to me.

Comment: @JonCuster That certainly depends on the exact circumstances, including questions of whether the current supervisor could continue the supervision despite being denied tenure, and/or whether another faculty member could take over the supervisor role.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper - sure, but neither situation will be ideal - the current supervisor will be busy finding someplace else, and another faculty member will have a start-up cost associated with bringing them up to speed. Likely better to get going while the going is good...

Comment: @JonCuster Rushing the completion of a PhD thesis is surely also not ideal. It's a real trade-off where the best solution depends on the exact circumstances.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper - I think the language used in the question already indicates the situation is far from ideal, even should the professor get tenure (or even without there being a tenure decision period).

Comment: Yes I agree about my post sounding like a rant perhaps because I feel distressed and I’m sorry about including perhaps irrelevant details. My question indeed was if a paper is accepted a month before tenure decisions are communicated would it help my advisor given this is a justification she is using to rush my paper. The answers seem to agree with what I instinctively feel, that it is unlikely. My best course of action perhaps is to just complete and leave asap. Thank you all for your time and responses!

Comment: A related question though what are my chances of landing a postdoc if it is known that my advisor was denied tenure if she is? Do potential postdoc advisors factor this in when judging applicants?

Comment: The request that you defend and submit a paper may be for *your* benefit.  Things can move awfully fast following a negative tenure outcome, and having a student finish up may be the best thing for a student looking in the face of a sudden lab closure and no advisor

Answer (score 6):

There are many questions in your post, so let me answer just the one that your title is about. I'm going to take your "grapevine" as truth, though as others have pointed out, the grapevine is rarely reliable. With that, let's get to it:

No, getting a single paper published is not going to change anything, especially if it is late in the game.[1] This is particularly true if the department (and at this time of year) the dean have already made their decisions and written their letters that accompany the file as it makes its way upward in the university. I cannot imagine a situation where a department would go back on its decision, retract the letter, and write a new one that states the opposite just because a single paper has been published after the original letter was written. Tenure decisions are generally not made on the basis of a single paper, but based on the entirety of the evidence. In other words, if someone has not been productive over the course of six years, then *that* is the evidence, and a single paper is not going to change the general pattern.

As a consequence, your adviser is clinging to straws believing that that paper is going to make a difference. That may be understandable from a human perspective, but the straw is not going to keep her afloat.

Of course, all of that puts you into an awkward spot. Others are already commenting on that part of your post.

---

[1] The usual caveat applies: Tens or hundreds of thousands of people have over the years gone through the tenure process. Surely there are cases where a single paper, accepted late in the process, made a difference. But just because it has happened does not mean that one should take into account as something that might apply to the current case.

Answer (score 3):

> if she is going to be denied tenure is even a last minute paper acceptance going to change the decision?

That is exceedingly unlikely.  One article in seven years is a huge problem.  Only an extraordinary achievement can fix that.  Details vary by university and discipline.

> Does student outcome ever factor in making tenure decisions?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't believe the grapevine. It may be accurate or not. The decision will be made by the normal faculty rules and I doubt that you would have much impact, especially via a submitted paper that you don't think is ready.

You are in a tough situation. I suggest that you talk to the administration (head, dean) about what your options are. Her tenure decision ideally shouldn't impact your graduation, but only they can say. You might require a "fill in" supervisor to get over the hump and the head/dean might be able to make that happen.

This is one reason that I always suggest students work with tenured faculty for dissertations so that this sort of thing won't occur. Too late for you now, of course, but the university has an obligation to provide you a path.

Ask the head about the effect of a paper and about the effect of a plea. Often, BTW, faculty who fail to obtain tenure get one more year so that they can get other employment. Probably not universal, but common. So, you may wind up OK if you can finish in a year without switching advisors.

I hate to suggest putting a guilt trip on the head, but...

You aren't responsible for the plight of your advisor and shouldn't suffer because of it.

When you discuss things with the head, if you can, make the conversation about your needs, not your advisor's failings as you see them.

Comment: + 1 for _You aren't responsible for the plight of your advisor and shouldn't suffer because of it._

Comment: +1 for "talk to administration and/or dean about options." I have friends who had to scramble when their advisor left academia. It's a pain, do whatever you can to prepare for it.

Comment: Trying my best to navigate this and have received a lot of helpful advice from this community so far. Then again I am hoping she doesn’t actually get denied tenure.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of at least two situations where negative tenure votes were successfully appealed at a high-ranking R1. I shared an office with the lab members in one case and they pushed hard to get all papers that were in process as far along as possible. This did seem to make a difference and the faculty member was granted tenure.

One additional note: the case I am referring to was also one where there was at least one year of stop the clock granted. (I believe there was part of the appeal related to this- some of the negative voters were not accounting for this.) A stop the clock does not imply that no work should have been happening. (You seem to think it was unfair that you worked during this times) It implies that the work is not at a full level and a 7 year time frame should be treated as a 6-year one for judging productivity.

Comment: Our case is a bit more complicated by the possibility of a grant renewal being denied too, and that the professor hasn’t been able to recruit many students we are at the end of seven years a three person one PI lab (several students have rotated close to 17 of which 2 joined). Could these be mitigating factors that can raise the chances of denial after reappeal too?

Comment: I really can’t speak to those factors. In the case I am thinking of they were not factors. The faculty member was beloved by students and lab members. No difficulty recruiting students. No difficulty getting grants, although always as part of a team of PIs and so there were some people who wanted to see solo PI grants.