# Importance of research team in PhD

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I have been accepted to two programs in education in the US. Both potential advisors are very active in research in different ways and advocated me a lot to the admission committee. The first uni has a very high reputation (top 50), and the advisor, an associate professor, is a leading expert in the field (Professor A). The second uni is top 160, and the advisor is an assistant professor (Professor B).

As far as I researched, most of Prof. A's PhD students are part-time students who hold other professional positions. In contrast, Prof. B's students are "traditional" and do the course in full-time mode. Furthermore, both profs often conduct research projects with other professors rather than students (evidence as recent years of research records). Therefore, I feel that I can have more chances of getting publications with seniors in the lab of Prof. B rather than in Prof. A's lab because A is busy and there are no full-time PhD students in the lab.

So my questions are:

1. If I choose Prof. A, what is your advice when working with a busy advisor? What should I do to get involved in more research projects and get publications during the PhD period?
2. If I choose Prof. B, to what extent does the ranking affect my career prospects (top 160)? To what extent can the publications replace the low rank? (How many publications, quality..)

Comment: It would be great to contact some students from  both teams and assess if your assumptions are really true. Publication records may not tell the entire story

Comment: I doubt that any program in Education actually functions as a lab. Much more likely to be individual work, I think.

Comment: @Buffy Education is pretty broad; on the side of ed psych and ed tech you'll see a lot more lab-like environment than ed policy, curriculum, etc.

Comment: There's a lot of questions here that are not entirely related. Please focus your Question on one question, although I'm not sure it will be on-topic.

Comment: Can you say more about the specific field within education? I might have a bit of general advice, but not for the question as stated.

Comment: For a warning about working with an untenured faculty member (assistant professor, say) see this question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/182213/75368

Comment: @AppliedAcademic I tried. However, as I mentioned, most of the students of prof A are professional so they are quite busy. I could only talk to one and they said that they don't do any research projects with the prof because they are busy with their full-time work. While students of prof B usually work on the projects with the advisor.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Sorry for not being clear. I edited the question.

Comment: @Hung Thanks for clarifying, but my multiple-questions comment still stands

Comment: @Buffy My area is Edu Policy

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- If I need to integrate to one question, this would be: How could I get more opportunities of involving in research projects (and have pubs) when working under a very busy advisor and a lot of part-time PhD students around?

Answer (score 4):

In the world of research, publications matter more than university ranking. The prestige of the lab group is only good so far as it helps you in producing quality publications in quality journals. If you go to a highly ranked program with a fancy-pants PI but you fail to produce, no one will care about the former points. Go to the lab that you will thrive in and that will help you get the most quality pubs, is my advice. From what you have shared, it sounds like you already know this is group B.

Comment: +1 for go where you will thrive. Which professor does/supervises work you are more interested in?